# Set Bounds of GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to set the limit the bounds of my image view, Or something to prevent the image/ view from zooming out or to the left as it looks pretty bad. Here is the problem [Looks Good, Only should be able to zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm9M2.png)... [Zoomed out, Looks Bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrCfl.png)

```
@IBAction func scaleView(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    //print(self.my_new_fullimage)

    self.view.transform = self.view.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y:  sender.scale)
    sender.scale = 1

}
@IBAction func panView(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Move the anchor point of the view's layer to the touch point
    // so that moving the view becomes simpler.
    let piece = gestureRecognizer.view
    //self.adjustAnchorPoint(gestureRecognizer: gestureRecognizer)

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        // Get the distance moved since the last call to this method.
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: piece?.superview)

        // Set the translation point to zero so that the translation distance
        // is only the change since the last call to this method. 
        piece?.center = CGPoint(x: ((piece?.center.x)! + translation.x), 
                                y: ((piece?.center.y)! + translation.y))
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: piece?.superview)

    }
}
```

Anything can help.

-Thanks!

Comment: What if you only transform the image view only, not the whole `view`?

Comment: Hmm, It seems close, The Scale View works when i change both "view" to "my_new_fullimage" but I don't see where that can get recognized in the san view. The scaling is fine but the pan is still able to go off bounds

Comment: For that you can just check whether the image will go out of the screen after the pan. If it will, don't transform it.

Comment: @Sweeper Would That be a bounds Property?